# Error when using curl php?

Tags: php, curl

```
#!/usr/bin/php -f
Notice: Undefined variable: argv in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\admin-ajax.php on line 12
```

This error message comes with my when I tried to get the code below  run using localhost server ( Xammp on windows7 ). It is a PHP curl exploit which has created by the tool RIPS.

```
{
 #!/usr/bin/php -f
<?php
#Userinput reaches sensitive sink when function screen_icon() is called.
# template.php curl exploit
#

//
// HTTP GET,

//

$target = $argv[1];

$username = "";
$password = "";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/wordpress3/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?post_type=22");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_LIMIT, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_LOW_SPEED_TIME, 3);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie_$target");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
$buf = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
unset($ch);

echo $buf;



?> }
```

Any suggestion to get this problem solved?

Comment: $argv is populated when you call the script from the command line

Comment: are you calling this script on the command line? Are you passing php the additional argument?

Comment: The `#!` line needs to be the first line of the script if you want to be able to run the script by typing its name as a command, instead of with `php scriptname`

Comment: No, i call the scrip file from browser!

Answer (score 1):

In a unix system the line `#!/usr/bin/php` is called shebang line because this combination of symbols `#!` that is called she bang.

The purpose of the she bang is to specify the interpreter of your script when you run it as a program.

So this it means that this script is made to be called and executed by command line.

The line which generate the error `$target = $argv[1];` actually it take the second argument you put in the command line.

Eg:

```
test\admin-ajax.php  site.com
        ^               ^
      argv[0]         argv[1]
```

But because you are not calling this script from command line but from browser it rises an error because the argv array is not initialised.

[argv documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php)

[shebang wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29)